# Why does MFunctor's 'hoist' not have 'Monad n' constraint?

Tags: haskell

I have a coroutine transformer

```
data Step y m a = Done a | Yield y (CoT y m a)

data CoT y m a = CoT (m (Step y m a))
```

with `Monad` instance

```
unCoT :: CoT y m a -> m (Step y m a)
unCoT (CoT m) = m

instance Monad m => Monad (CoT y m) where
    return  = CoT . return . Done
    CoT x >>= f = CoT $ do
      x' <- x
      case x' of
        Done a -> unCoT (f a)
        Yield y x' -> return (Yield y (x' >>= f))
```

If I define an `MFunctor` class with `Monad m` *and* `Monad n` constraints I can define `hoist`

```
class MFunctor t where
  hoist :: (Monad n, Monad m) => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b

instance MFunctor (CoT y) where
  hoist f (CoT m) = CoT $ do
    step <- f m
    return (case step of Done x     -> Done x
                         Yield y m' -> Yield y (hoist f m'))
```

But `mmorph`'s `hoist` only has a `Monad m` constraint.  Can I define my `hoist` without it, or is this a lack of generality of `MFunctor`?

EDIT: I worked out it *is* possible!  But my question still stands: are we sure there's no lack of generality here?

```
instance MFunctor (CoT y) where
  hoist f (CoT m) = CoT $ f $ do
    step <- m
    return (case step of Done x     -> Done x
                         Yield y m' -> Yield y (hoist f m'))
```

Answer (score 8):

`mmorph` was developed in the context of the `pipes-3.*` series (it used to be [an internal `pipes` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-3.1.0/docs/Control-MFunctor.html)), which had functions like this:

```
raise
    :: (Monad m, MFunctor t1, MonadTrans t2)
    => t1 m r -> t1 (t2 m) r
raise = hoist lift
```

If you add the `Monad n` constraint to `hoist` then you have to add a `Monad (t2 m)` constraint to `raise`.  I generally try to minimize constraints in my libraries and I couldn't find any `MFunctor` instances that needed the `Monad n` constraint, so I removed it.

Side note: `CoT y m a` is the same thing as `Producer y m a` from `pipes`, which already has an `MFunctor` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any type `t` for which you can define `hoist' :: (Monad m, Monad n) => (forall t. m t -> n t) -> t m a -> t n a` as a `MFunctor`. But you will only be able to use the resulting `t n a` if you have a `Monad` instance on `n`. We do this by deferring the application of the natural transformation. Or a fancy way of saying this would be applying the coyoneda lemma.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, GADTs #-}

import Control.Monad.Morph

-- Slightly weaker than MFunctor due to the monad constraint on n.
class MFunctor' t where
  hoist' :: (Monad m, Monad n) => (forall b. m b -> n b) -> t m a -> t n a

data MCoyoneda t n a where
  MCoyoneda :: Monad m => (forall b. m b -> n b) -> t m a -> MCoyoneda t n a

liftMCoyoneda :: Monad m => t m a -> MCoyoneda t m a
liftMCoyoneda = MCoyoneda id

lowerMCoyoneda' :: (MFunctor' t, Monad n) => MCoyoneda t n a -> t n a
lowerMCoyoneda' (MCoyoneda f tma) = hoist' f tma

-- The result is actually slightly stronger than 'MFunctor', as we do not need
-- a monad for 'm' either.
hoistMCoyoneda :: (forall b. m b -> n b) -> MCoyoneda t m a -> MCoyoneda t n a
hoistMCoyoneda f (MCoyoneda trans tma) = MCoyoneda (f . trans) tma

instance MFunctor (MCoyoneda t) where
  hoist = hoistMCoyoneda
```

So I don't think we loose generality, because if you can not implement an instance for `MFunctor` then nothing is lost by the `Monad` constraint on `lowerMCoyoneda'`.

I discovered this running into a [similar problem with `RVarT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797501/implementing-an-mfunctor-instance-for-rvart/41803584#41803584).