# Implementing an MFunctor instance for RVarT

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Is it possible to implement an [`MFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.9/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) instance for [`RVarT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rvar-0.2.0.3/docs/Data-RVar.html#t:RVarT)?

So far I've come up with the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Data.RVar                        -- from rvar
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift) -- from transformers

hoistRVarT :: Monad m => (forall t. n t -> m t) -> RVarT n a -> RVarT m a
hoistRVarT f rv = sampleRVarTWith (lift . f) rv
```

However this can not be used as a definition of `hoist` for `MFunctor`, due to the `Monad` constraint on `m` incurred by `lift`. The problem is, that I couldn't find another way to lift the the resulting monad into `RVarT` without `lift`. But I think conceptually it should be possible, since `RVarT` should be similar to `StateT` and there is an `MFunctor` instance for `StateT`. The problem is that I couldn't find anything in the API of `rvar` or `random-fu` which exposed such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RVarT m a` is a `newtype` for `PromptT Prim m a`, where `PromptT` is defined in [`Control.Monad.Prompt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadPrompt-1.0.0.5/docs/Control-Monad-Prompt.html). `PromptT Prim m a` is a `newtype` for `Prompt (Lift Prim m) a`. This, in turn, is a `newtype` for

```
forall b. (a -> b) -> (forall x. Lift Prim m x -> (x -> b) -> b) -> b
```

You can unwrap the whole thing with `unsafeCoerce`:

```
fromRVarT :: RVarT m a -> (a -> b) -> (forall x. Lift Prim m x -> (x -> b) -> b) -> b
fromRVarT = unsafeCoerce

toRVarT :: (forall b. (a -> b) -> (forall x. Lift Prim m x -> (x -> b) -> b) -> b) -> RVarT m a
toRVarT = unsafeCoerce
```

`Prim` isn't exported, but since you shouldn't need to touch it in the first place, and you're assembling and disassembling the whole thing with `unsafeCoerce`, you can just define:

```
data Prim a
```

You can write an `MFunctor` instance for `Lift`:

```
instance MFunctor (Lift f) where
  hoist _ (Effect p) = Effect p
  hoist phi (Lift m) = Lift (phi m)
```

And then you can unwrap the `RVarT`, hoist all the `Lift`s passed to its prompting function, and wrap it again:

```
instance MFunctor RVarT where
  hoist phi rv = toRVarT $ \done prm -> fromRVarT rv done (\l -> prm $ hoist phi l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick that works for this and similar cases if you do not need to be able to actually use a value `RVarT m` without a monad instance for `m`. It works by deferring the application of the natural transformation until we actually need to get out a value. It would still be nice if there was a proper instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.RVar
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Monad.Morph
import Control.Monad (ap)

hoistRVarT :: Monad m => (forall t. n t -> m t) -> RVarT n a -> RVarT m a
hoistRVarT f = sampleRVarTWith (lift . f)

data RVarTFun m a = forall n. RVarTFun 
  { transformation :: forall t. n t -> m t
  , rvart :: RVarT n a }

-- You can only get a value out if you have a monad for m.
getRVarTFun :: Monad m => RVarTFun m a -> RVarT m a
getRVarTFun (RVarTFun t ma) = hoistRVarT t ma

wrapRVarTFun :: RVarT m a -> RVarTFun m a
wrapRVarTFun = RVarTFun id

-- Actually the result is slightly stronger than MFunctor because we don't need
-- a Monad on n.
hoistRVarTFun :: (forall t. n t -> m t) -> RVarTFun n a -> RVarTFun m a
hoistRVarTFun f (RVarTFun t nx) = RVarTFun (f . t) nx

instance MFunctor RVarTFun where
  hoist = hoistRVarTFun
```

A more general implementation of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391770/why-does-mfunctors-hoist-not-have-monad-n-constraint/41816815#41816815).

Comment: This is an application of the co-Yoneda lemma.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thank you, I wondered if it already existed and had a name.